# How to ignore files and directories in opengrok used from docker?

Tags: docker, opengrok

This is how I was doing that in some very old version of Opengrok:

```
docker run -d (...) -e IGNORE_PATTERNS="-i *.swp -i */build/*" (...)
```

Now I'm trying more recent version (1.5). I've found info that IGNORE_PATTERNS was changed to OPENGROK_IGNORE_PATTERNS but it doesn't work for me (opengrok works but files are not ignored).

This is my current command:

```
docker run -d -v /tmp/test1/:/opengrok/src -e OPENGROK_IGNORE_PATTERNS="-i *.swp -i d:build" -p 9876:8080 opengrok/docker:1.5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently OPENGROK_IGNORE_PATTERNS was once again changed. This time to **INDEXER_OPT** which works.

Answer (score 0):

Use the INDEXER_OPT environment variable to pass extra options to OpenGrok Indexer.

See more info about using a docker container for OpenGrok [here](https://github.com/oracle/opengrok/blob/master/docker/README.md).

Note: in [release 1.6.4](https://github.com/oracle/opengrok/releases/tag/1.6.4), a bug in INDEXER_OPT variable was fixed. Unfortunately, the release notes don't tell what was the issue and when the issue was introduced.